# Rails: Unobtrusive DELETE when JavaScript turned off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

How does unobtrusive delete work if JavaScript is turned off?

It seems like you just get a link to the record, given that data-method='delete' is ignored. I guess that's the intention, it's certainly quick and easy for the developer, but if that's the case, it doesn't really stack up with what the user would expect if they click a "delete" link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is really an [excellent blog post](http://ryantownsend.co.uk/post/13058102942/unobtrusive-object-deletion-in-rails) covering just this.

Comment: Thanks, a little effort to set up a separate page for all cases, but I might do a variant with an in-page link to a delete button. Mainly, I'm pleased to get confirmation this really is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `?_method=delete` to your delete links.  Completely untested code:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", record_path(@record, :_method => "delete") %>
```

Comment: Tried it, but the _method was ignored, it just shows the record as before.